# AlertController not found on ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, uialertcontroller

i am using ionic2@beta version 35.
I am trying to use an alert box but i keep getting

> Error TS2305: Module '"/home/webshinobis/boom/node_modules/ionic-angular/index"' has no exported member 'AlertController'. This is my code for the alert service:

```js
import {AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';

export class alert {

  optionsBoxOpen: boolean;
  optionsBoxData: any;

  constructor(private alertController: AlertController) {}

  showCheckbox() {
    let alert = this.alertController.create();
    alert.setTitle('Which planets have you visited?');

    alert.addInput({
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Alderaan',
      value: 'value1',
      checked: true
    });

    alert.addInput({
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Bespin',
      value: 'value2'
    });

    alert.addButton('Cancel');
    alert.addButton({
      text: 'Okay',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Checkbox data:', data);
        this.optionsBoxOpen = false;
        this.optionsBoxData = data;
      }
    });
    alert.present();

  }
}
```

Comment: +1. Inspecting ionic-angular/components.d.ts I get the same error regarding components/alert/alert having no exported member AlertController...

Comment: The AlertController is not found in ionic beta 11 released yesterday so you will have to upgrade to use it

Comment: The AlertController is not found in ionic beta 11 released yesterday( august 6th) so you will have to upgrade to use it. check the [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-beta-11)